# Why does bracket require `release` to produce result that is ignored?

Tags: haskell, exception

```
bracket
        :: IO a         -- ^ computation to run first (\"acquire resource\")
        -> (a -> IO b)  -- ^ computation to run last (\"release resource\")
        -> (a -> IO c)  -- ^ computation to run in-between
        -> IO c         -- returns the value from the in-between computation
bracket before after thing =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a <- before
    r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after a
    _ <- after a
    return r
```

Is this related to some API design pattern or conventions ? Why not use the following part of signature?

```
        -> (a -> IO ())  -- ^ computation to run last (empty result)
```

or

```
        -> (a -> IO a)  -- ^ computation to run last (`a` cannot be ignored)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have it backwards - `bracket` will ignore the result of the release operation for you.

If the signature of the release operation was `a -> IO ()` then you would have to supply a function which always returned `()`. By making the signature `a -> IO b` your release function can return anything since
the type variable `b` is not referenced anywhere else in the signature -i.e.
it is totally unrelated to any of the other type variables.

Comment: Why then `main` does not have `IO a` type?

Comment: `main` can have `IO a` or `IO Int` as a type.

Comment: @sevo, it's probably best to stick to the rule that `main` should have type `IO ()` if the program can exit by completing the main action, and type `IO a` or `IO Void` if the program only exits as the result of an uncaught exception or an explicit call to `exitWith` or similar. But `main` is allowed to have any `IO` type.